# Style key syntax problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I tried both

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\tikzset{axeseul/.style={%
/pgfplots/axis x line align=center, % rien en y     
/pgfplots/axis y line align=none,   % sans axe y
%ymin=0,ymax=1
red}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[style=axeseul,ymin=0,ymax=1] 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\tikzstyle{axeseul}=[%
    /pgfplots/axis x line align=center, % rien en y     
    /pgfplots/axis y line align=none,   % sans axe y
    %ymin=0,ymax=1
    red]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[style=axeseul,ymin=0,ymax=1] 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Both give me red axis but no center and no none ...
Where is the mystake ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As **percusse** mentions in his comment, the problem with your settings is that 
`tikzset` sets the key `/tikz/pgfplots/...` so nothing is read and executed. You should use `\pgfplotsset`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{axeseul/.style={%
axis x line =center,     
axis y line =none,
red}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axeseul,ymin=0,ymax=1]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank's it works fine, but I want ymin=0 and ymax=1 at once in the axeseul style. Is it possible ? I tried to add them, but it does nothing.

Comment: @Tarass you can add those options: `\pgfplotsset{axeseul/.style={%
axis x line =center,     
axis y line =none,
ymin=0,ymax=1,
red}}` and remove them from the `axis` environment if the styles has already been applied.

Comment: Ok, I forgot to  add : compat=newest, it work now. Thank you.